# set height on element after a slidedown()

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

i got a click thats triggers a `slideDown()` on a div. my thought is that after the div is expanded i set the height of another div based on the expanded div. The problem becomes that it takes the height and sets it before the other div is slided fully, for a fact it takes the height of the div that it got before it slide out.

is there a way to pause everything until the `slideDown()` is done?

```
$div.slideDown();

//sets the height of the Container
$outer_container.css("height", $inner_container.outerHeight());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [callback function](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/#callback-function), which only runs once the animation is complete:

```
$div.slideDown(400, function() {
    //sets the height of the Container
    $outer_container.css("height", $inner_container.outerHeight());
});
```

Or, to use a slightly more compact apprach:

```
$div.slideDown(400, function() {
    $outer_container.height($inner_container.outerHeight());
});
```